# Eigenvalue-related statements

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector, perturbation-theory

(I understand this question might not be appropriate for this website, but it has been asked on MathStackexchange and did not receive any replies even with a bounty)

How can I prove that the following statements are equivalent?

1. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A+\delta A$, where $\|\delta A\|_{2}\leq \epsilon$
2. $\exists u\in \mathbb{C}^{m}$ such that $\|(A-\lambda I)u\|_{2}\leq\epsilon$ and $\|u\|_{2}=1$
3. $\sigma_{n}(\lambda I - A)\leq \epsilon$, where $\sigma_{n}$ is the smallest singular value of A
4. $\|(\lambda A - I)^{-1}\|\geq \epsilon^{-1}$

I am using An Introduction to Numerical Analysis by Endre Süli and David F. Mayers but it's not been very helpful. If you could recommend me another textbook I would be very grateful.

Comment: Perhaps $\|\cdot\|_2$ should just be $\|\cdot\|$ in statement 1?

Comment: I have double-checked, it's $\|\cdot\|_2$

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. Voting to close.

Comment: It can be closed, Denis Serre's answer has been more than helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather classical. The set of such $\lambda$'s is called the $\epsilon$-pseudo-spectrum. It is presented in many books on numerical linear algebra. I suggest S.K. Godunov *Modern aspects of linear algebra*, AMS (1998).